# Htaccess redirect different domains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect all parked domains from my hosting to a specific page. Is there an efficient way of using 301 redirect in htaccess to do so.
The example is below

```
www.domain1.com -> www.mydomain.com/domain1.com
www.domain2.com -> www.mydomain.com/domain2.com
```

If you have Idea or a tip how to extract root url and put it in a new url and then do a redirect please let me know, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this redirect rule in site root .htaccess or Apache config:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example.com/%1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Should I write somewhere the redirection url? I mean www.mydomain.com from the case above

Comment: No, this is not redirecting. the problem is that we have multiple domains and that the root url must be dynamic